# Create shortcut to cmd to execute a batch file in Inno Setup

Tags: batch-file, cmd, inno-setup

I use a batch script `start.bat` to run my program. I create a shortcut for this purposes as shown below:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\start.bat"; \
    IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\start.bat"; \
    IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

In order for the user to be allowed to drag the shortcut to a batch file to the taskbar (Windows 10) I have to modify the shortcut path from `E:\Soft\MyProgram\start.bat` to `cmd /c E:\Soft\MyProgram\start.bat`. But I can't just change the path to `Filename: "cmd /c  {app}\start.bat";` it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd /c E:\Soft\MyProgram\start.bat
```

The above command executes `cmd.exe` program with `/c E:\Soft\MyProgram\start.bat` as its parameters.

In Inno Setup `Icons` section, you specify the parameters using [`Parameters` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=Parameters):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "cmd"; \
    Parameters: "/c E:\Soft\MyProgram\start.bat"; \
    IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

- Though instead of hard-coding `cmd`, you should use [`{cmd}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=cmd).
- Similarly, I assume that instead of `E:\Soft\MyProgram`, you should use `{app}`.
- Wrap the path to double quotes, in case it contains spaces.
- In some cases, the batch file might be designed to only work when executed from its directory. For that add [`WorkingDir` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=WorkingDir).

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{cmd}"; \
    Parameters: "/c ""{app}\start.bat"""; WorkingDir: "{app}" \
    IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate your help, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/69083021/13116250 here is a solution to modify script:

```
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/c cd /d ""{app}"" && launch.bat"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/c cd /d ""{app}"" && launch.bat"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

You should first cd to the app directory and then run a batch file.

Comment: Instead of `cd`, use `WorkingDir` parameter. + Whether you really need that depends on the application. It's not a general requirement, as your answer implies.